# How to render special characters in html

Tags: java, html, character-encoding, inputstream

Am am reading html text from a resourse file as

```
InputStream fstream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream(filename);
myString = IOUtils.toString(fstream, "UTF-8");
```

But if html contains special chars as

```
McDonald's
```

it convert it to  `McDonald?s`, i can  resolve it if i replace `'` with `apos` but is there any other way to do it. is it some encoding isseu?? as its very much tedious to replace every single char since my file contains these special chars in thousands.

Thanks,

Comment: Your file probably isn't encoded in UTF-8. Use the appropriate encoding to read your file, and everything should be fine.

Comment: @JBNizet - Am I missing something or is that not what this does `IOUtils.toString(fstream, "UTF-8");`? Thanks! :)

Comment: @JBNizet :  myString = IOUtils.toString(fstream, "UTF-8");
, I have used it. what do you mean by appropriate encoding.

Comment: @jmort253 : i have 200 files that all contains 100s of diff special char..:(

Comment: Every file in the world is not encoded in UTF8. If you try to decode a file encoded in ISO-8859-1 using UTF-8, it won't work. The encoding used to read the file must be the same as the one which was used to create it. That's like trying to open your neighbour's door with your own key. It doesn't work. You need your neighbour's key.

Comment: @JBNizet: Ok, but how to know which encoding have been used while writing html file. I have <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta> in my html file.

Comment: Then it should be UTF-8, or the person that wrote it specified UTF-8 in the file but encoded it in another encoding. Where does the file come from? Have you tried your default platform encoding?

Comment: @JBNizet: please read my full post. I told am reading it from resource folder that contains html files and i am reading those file and these html files have <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta> means they are encoded in utf-8. and at the time reading am using myString = IOUtils.toString(fstream, "UTF-8");
So as per ur above comment it should work..but its not

Comment: No, it doesn't mean they are encoded in UTF-8. It means they **SHOULD BE** encoded in UTF-8. If the creator of the file doesn't understand what encodings are, he could perfectly have encoded the files in ISO-8859-1, and have added this meta section in the file. Maybe he just copied 'n pasted it from somewhere without even knowing what it means. Ask the creator of the file how he created the file.

Comment: I craeted file, i just did copy paste, and while saving it asked to me to save for some file i saved it using utf-8

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks alot. U saved my time. yes it worked, actually fiels were in ANSI , i changed them to utf-=8 and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Try a different encoding. Possibly be `Cp1252` or `ISO-8859-1`. You can find more character encodings in http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets (use the *preferred MIME name*) or take at look in [Character encoding - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings).

Comment: Cp1252 is the most probable encoding, but its recommended name is windows-1252. If it fails, there is no point in trying ISO-8859-1 (which is the same as windows-1252 except that there are control characters in place of some printable characters). A better try is then windows-1251, but there are many possibilities – information about the origin of the files might help greatly in the guesswork. And you can probably open a file in a good editor, like NotePad++, and try different encodings there.

Comment: When not specified `-Dfile.encoding`, I get `Cp1252` on my computer. But usually I work with UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

use this meta tag intead of utf8 if your site is in english language for multiple languages you have to use utf8

```
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

Comment: yes, but i need some common that would work both on english or with other as with japanese, arabic